# Data Importing using Azure Web Jobs to Azure SQL

Tags: json, azure, data-import, webjob

Just looking for some advice on best way to handle data importing via scheduled Web Jobs.
I have 8 json files that are imported every 5 hours via an FTP client using JSON serializer into memory and then these JSON objects are processed and inserted into Azure SQL using EF6.  Each file is processed in a loop sequentially as I wanted to make sure that all data is inserted correctly as when I tried to use a Parallel ForEach some of the data was not being inserted on related tables.  So if the WebJob fails i know there has been an error and we can run again, problem is this is now taking a long time to complete, near on 2hrs as we have a lot data - each file has 500 locations and each location has 11 days and 24 hour data.

Anyone have any ideas on how to do this quicker whilst ensuring that the data is always inserted correctly or handle any errors.  Was looking at using Storage queues but we may need to point to other databases in the future or can I use 1 web job per file so have 8 web jobs for each file being scheduled every 5 hours as i think there is a limit to the number of web jobs i can run per day.

Or is there an alternative way of importing data into Azure SQL that can be scheduled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Web Jobs ([via the Web Jobs SDK](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-storage-blobs-how-to/)) can monitor and process BLOBs.  There is no need to create a scheduled job.  The SDK can monitor for new BLOBs and process them as they are created.  You could break up your processing to smaller files and load them as they are created.

Azure Stream Analytics has similar capabilities.

Comment: ok - will take a look, Stream Analytics seems overkill to essentially do a batch import into SqlAzure unless i am wrong.